# Found a lost locked iPhone 6

Tags: iphone

So a friend of mine found a lost iPhone 6. It has activation lock, and I see no information on the previous owner.
I see the IMEI on the back, is it possible to get any information from Apple or whatever about who the user is? if I could get my hands on the email address, at least, I could contact him/her.

Any help?

Comment: Depending on the configuration of the iPhone you could try to ask Siri questions like "where do I live" or try to tap on emergency on the unlock screen and check whether they configured the emergency pass with "in case of emergency" numbers.

Comment: idk about where you live, but hanging onto something you found qualifies as theft in the UK. You should have taken it to the police. Afaik, if unclaimed after 3 months, *then* you can have the brick back, as finder.

Comment: I didn't find it, but I did try my damn best to get ahold of the previous owner with the tools I had. I don't even have it, the finder does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple or the phone carrier won't likely give your friend any information about the owner, but I think that your only option for your friend is to turn it in to an Apple Store near him, tell them where/when he found it, and hope that Apple gets the phone back to the owner. Without any information about the phone other than the IMEI, there's not a lot he can do.

Comment: I'll try with the local carriers first, they have provided current or past numbers in the past in similar cases. Then I'll try the apple store. Thanks.

Comment: Your local police station, constabulary or gendarmerie mat be of help, too. It may have been reported missing or stolen. Until then, leave it on and charged up - the one may actually have turned on Find My iPhone. Sadly, many people _do not_ enable Find My iPhone.

Comment: I find it extremely odd that Apple does not provide a service in which they can help you contact the owner. They freaking have the device ID and what iCloud account it used! I could be sending an email to this person.

Comment: That would really be the ultimate stalking service… steal someone's phone & you also get access to their home address & phone number. You can see why that's not really an option? Not everyone is as honest as you would hope. The original owner's main problem is they took not the slightest step to help themselves in such a circumstance. It takes about 30s to enable Find My iPhone.

Comment: Indeed. I'll try today with an Apple store for the last time before this pricey iPhone 6 fulfills his destiny of becoming a really expensive paperweight.

Comment: I called an apple store today finally. What they told me is that if the phone is showing the activation lock, is because someone tried to restore it, and that's why it isn't showing the Find My Phone lock screen with contact data. So actually my last chance is my gf, who works in a local carrier, trying to find out the phone number associated with the imei, if it belongs to said carrier.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody calls or messages the lost phone, and a notification appears on the lock screen, you can call them back without unlocking the phone. I discovered this when my wife lost her iPhone (a 5S running iOS 7), and the kind stranger who found it called me after I sent her an iMessage.

Answer (score -2):

Hold down the home button and ask Siri, "Whose phone is this?"

Comment: Impossible from activation lock. The phone has since turned into a insanely expensive paper weight, a friend has it, if she didn't throw it away already.